# What state structure is related to each interval $z$ in Hyperscaling violating black holes?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, astrophysics

Hyperscaling violating black holes are defined by parameters such as $z$ and $θ$. My main question is: what kind of state structure corresponds to each value of $z$, or what does it signify and relate to in terms of theory? What are the bounds of the $θ$ parameter? Can it take any positive or negative value?